# Photo on mug/t-shirt

Tags: jquery, image, gwt, image-processing

I am developing a web application using GWT and JQuery for UI development. In this application customer can upload the photo and print the photo on mug/t-shirt etc. Something like this

I don't see any problems till the image uploading, but not able to proceed further and display image on mug. I searched a lot, but I am not getting any API for this, maybe I am missing something. Is there any API for doing this? Please help me on how to display an image to mug/t-shirt?

Please help..!!!

Thanks..!!!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and after a little research I found this api -
https://www.printful.com/docs/generator

I Think This Will Solve The Problem.

You will need to send the Image To Printful using the Method and the configuration data as described in the API Docs.

P.S. -  I do realize that this question is years old but maybe my answer will help new people who look for it.

I Hope That I was of help.

Answer (score 0):

To my big surprise, such an API does exist - if you are willing to work with Zazzle as your supplier:

http://www.zazzle.com/sell/developers/createaproductapi

Other suppliers of custom products may have their own APIs.

If do not want to use a supplier API, you will have to create this functionality on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I just went through the Zazzle API. It seems that if I use this customer will be redirected to the Zazzle website, which I would like to avoid.. :( Is there anything available which I can integrate in my code? rather than redirecting customers to other web sites? Thanks again..!

Comment: Why do you expect such an API to exist?

Comment: Yeah,you are right. I tried few things like, but not able to get the desired look and feel. Any idea on using which technology(Java related) this can be easily achieved?